# PHP's unpack method functionality in Java

Tags: java, php

I am wondering what the algorithm behind `unpack()` method in PHP is? Is there maybe an equivalent in Java which I could use?

*What would be the best way to implement PHP `unpack()` method in Java?*

Comment: are you attempting to unpack data packed in php in java? is this a php -> java interop question?

Comment: PHP is open source. Check the algoritcm at php/ext/standard/pack.c
No full implementation of that is know to me in java.

Comment: @gid No, I am looking at php code which I try to implement in Java. Specifically this code: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299003/how-to-convert-openssh-public-key-file-format-to-pem/3303128#3303128

Comment: @Imre Good point, I will take a look at the source.

Answer (score 2):

The nearest functionality is the DataInputStream/DataOutputStream pair.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the closest in java in Object Serialisation.

See `java.io.ObjectOutputStream` and `java.io.ObjectInputStream`

as always there is a library method to wrap this stuff up a couple of nice convenient methods

in [commons-lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/):

- [SerializationUtils.serialize(Serializable);](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/SerializationUtils.html#serialize(java.io.Serializable))
- [SerializationUtils.deserialize(byte[]);](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/lang/SerializationUtils.html#deserialize(byte[]))

But this isn't going to help you with php to java interop.