# Convert ssh public key to pem format

Tags: ruby, encoding, openssl, openssh

I'm getting a public key from the github api, so it's in the format it needs to be for ssh to read it.

I'd like to get formatted as a PEM so that I can work with it using ruby's OpenSSL library, specifically I need an `OpenSSL::PKey::RSA` instance.

essentially, I'd like this command in Ruby:

```
ssh-keygen -f testing_rsa.pub  -e -m pem
```

I found the [SSHKey](https://github.com/bensie/sshkey) gem, but it doesn't seem to do this specific thing.

Is there a way to do this with OpenSSL or another library or do I need to resort to what these [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3299003/how-to-convert-openssh-public-key-file-format-to-pem) answers are suggesting and convert it by hand?

Comment: How about just run that command with system from Ruby?

Comment: That's always an option, I was just hoping to not have to do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
require 'open3'

def key_file_in_pem_format key_file
  stdout, status = Open3::capture2('ssh-keygen', '-f', key_file, '-e', '-m', 'pem')
  raise unless status == 0
  stdout
end
```

This returns the output of the ssh-keygen program as a string.