# java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.io.IOException: unexpected end-of-contents marker

Tags: java, security, bouncycastle, public-key, key-pair

I'm trying to convert a `.pub` file's contents to a `PublicKey` and then convert the `PublicKey` back into a `String` in order to determine if the conversion is working and does not change the key in the process.

**id_rsa.pub**:

```
ssh-rsa AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC0zszKhcZTC8xJidUszmRn4Tr/FxPs04wpCzEstebfTW7Bvqgtt+OdvxoNyYM0LAEnxEF4XhAWcsX7VJJqstZLpDqlKDXFr2d0aVIjksCpZt+ftVRwYHRoERhEOP/UmPFb5rKIkhQbED2kTWg11mW9soc6BhwB3THn/Cyo3t1u2vWjEySgPhKeA3Xzh+5eqV7CUD8V6S7OAT7T9ijf7sRV0R8rwHgTLWJ8+dETnY3L3N0fEaNuaayeNblHqrL53/1+tsBBUF3bAS+1GE6oniSeM/yhtfzf2x+O5MDlVVMbOCC/v+FnfIIEKLA+v1xDSAha7C5cHh82TxToWXsbjqGD me@mail
```

**Converter.java**

```
public static final synchronized PublicKey base64ToPublicKey(final String algorithm, final String base64) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        BASE64Decoder decoder = new BASE64Decoder();
        byte[] sigBytes2 = decoder.decodeBuffer(base64);
        X509EncodedKeySpec x509KeySpec = new X509EncodedKeySpec(sigBytes2);
        KeyFactory keyFact = KeyFactory.getInstance(algorithm, "BC");
        return keyFact.generatePublic(x509KeySpec);
    }

    public static final synchronized String publicKeyToBase64(final PublicKey publicKey) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
        byte[] publicKeyBytes = publicKey.getEncoded();
        BASE64Encoder encoder = new BASE64Encoder();
        return encoder.encode(publicKeyBytes);
    }
```

When I run:

```
PublicKey test1 = base64ToPublicKey("RSA", "AAAAB3NzaC1yc2EAAAADAQABAAABAQC0zszKhcZTC8xJidUszmRn4Tr/FxPs04wpCzEstebfTW7Bvqgtt+OdvxoNyYM0LAEnxEF4XhAWcsX7VJJqstZLpDqlKDXFr2d0aVIjksCpZt+ftVRwYHRoERhEOP/UmPFb5rKIkhQbED2kTWg11mW9soc6BhwB3THn/Cyo3t1u2vWjEySgPhKeA3Xzh+5eqV7CUD8V6S7OAT7T9ijf7sRV0R8rwHgTLWJ8+dETnY3L3N0fEaNuaayeNblHqrL53/1+tsBBUF3bAS+1GE6oniSeM/yhtfzf2x+O5MDlVVMbOCC/v+FnfIIEKLA+v1xDSAha7C5cHh82TxToWXsbjqGD");
```

I get back:

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.io.IOException: unexpected end-of-contents marker
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(Unknown Source)
    at org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKKeyFactory$RSA.engineGeneratePublic(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:328)
    at base64ToPublicKey(Converter.java:216)
    at main(Converter.java:283)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**OpenSSH public key files** (`id_*.pub` also the entries in `known_hosts` and `authorized_keys`) for SSH2 use an OpenSSH-specific variant of an SSH-specific format, see [rfc4716](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4716) which is in turn based on the SSH2 wire format (as linked) [rfc4253 6.6](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4253#section-6.6), which is **not the 'X.509' format Java crypto uses**. (OpenSSH file formats for SSH1 were different, but SSH1 is long broken and should not be used.)

To convert this in Java see [convert openSSH rsa key to javax.crypto.Cipher compatible format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365940/convert-openssh-rsa-key-to-javax-crypto-cipher-compatible-format) .

It's easier to avoid the problem.

**Bypass 1:** If you have reasonably recent OpenSSH (6.0 is okay, not sure for earlier), use

```
ssh-keygen -e -m PKCS8 -f id_rsa.pub >pub.pem # change filename as needed
```

to convert to 'X.509' (really SubjectPublicKeyInfo aka SPKI) in PEM form. (Yes they do use the name PKCS8 to mean SPKI; [it's crazy](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/27913/why-can-ssh-keygen-export-a-public-key-in-pem-pkcs8-format).) Then read this in Java by discarding the BEGIN and END lines, decode everything in between (less the line breaks) from base64 to `byte[]`, and put that in `X509EncodedKeySpec` as you have now. Or if you have OpenSSL you can convert to DER form

```
openssl rsa -pubin -in pub.pem -out pub.der -outform der # any version
openssl pkey -pubin -in pub.pem -out pub.der -outform der # 1.0.0 up
```

and then read the DER file with no change at all into an `X509EncodedKeySpec`.

**Bypass 2:** if you have the **private key**, and it is NOT OpenSSH's 'new' format (optional since 6.5 (edit) and *default* since 7.8), and you have OpenSSL, get the public key in SPKI (Java-friendly) format with one of

```
openssl rsa -in id_rsa -pubout -out pub.pem # default PEM
openssl rsa -in id_rsa -pubout -out pub.der -outform der # DER
openssl pkey -in id_rsa -pubout -out pub.pem # default PEM, 1.0.0 up
openssl pkey -in id_rsa -pubout -out pub.der -outform der # DER, 1.0.0
```