# Java ssh-rsa string to public key

Tags: java, encryption, ssh, rsa, public-key-encryption

I want to get the public key of the content of an `.pub` file. This is an example what the content of a `.pub` file looks like(generated with `ssh-keygen`):

```
ssh-rsa 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 test@test.com
```

If I am right this is not the public key, but it is possible to get the public key from this string.

This answer gives answer to my question https://stackoverflow.com/a/19387517/2735398
But the answer doesn't seem to work. I get an exception:

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: invalid key format
```

When looking at the comments of the answer I am not the only person with the problem...

How can I fix the exception? Or is there another way to get the public key from the string?

Comment: Possible duplicate. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706177/how-to-generate-ssh-compatible-id-rsa-pub-from-java and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3588120/given-a-java-ssh-rsa-publickey-how-can-i-build-an-ssh2-public-key.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to generate ssh compatible id\_rsa(.pub) from Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706177/how-to-generate-ssh-compatible-id-rsa-pub-from-java)

Comment: I changed my question. I don't think it is a duplicate anymore.

Comment: You need to base64 decode the encoded bits first. Those bits start with 'AAAA' and end with '=='.

Comment: your linked #11410770 is about publickeys in the X.509-based (SPKI) format used by OpenSSL and Java, which is almost completely unlike the format used by OpenSSH. The proposed dupe #3706177 is for Java to OpenSSH. **For OpenSSH to Java see** https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3531506/using-public-key-from-authorized-keys-with-java-security and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19365940/convert-openssh-rsa-key-to-javax-crypto-cipher-compatible-format and maybe https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39105031/java-security-spec-invalidkeyspecexception-java-io-ioexception-unexpected-end (mine)

Answer (score 5):

Here is my SSH RSA -> RSAPublicKey converter implementation. I've found key format description somewhere in the net, so thanks to the one who provided it.

```
public class CertificateUtils {
    private static final int VALUE_LENGTH = 4;
    private static final byte[] INITIAL_PREFIX = new byte[]{0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x07, 0x73, 0x73, 0x68, 0x2d, 0x72, 0x73, 0x61};
    private static final Pattern SSH_RSA_PATTERN = Pattern.compile("ssh-rsa[\\s]+([A-Za-z0-9/+]+=*)[\\s]+.*");

// SSH-RSA key format
//
//        00 00 00 07             The length in bytes of the next field
//        73 73 68 2d 72 73 61    The key type (ASCII encoding of "ssh-rsa")
//        00 00 00 03             The length in bytes of the public exponent
//        01 00 01                The public exponent (usually 65537, as here)
//        00 00 01 01             The length in bytes of the modulus (here, 257)
//        00 c3 a3...             The modulus

    public static RSAPublicKey parseSSHPublicKey(String key) throws InvalidKeyException {
        Matcher matcher = SSH_RSA_PATTERN.matcher(key.trim());
        if (!matcher.matches()) {
            throw new InvalidKeyException("Key format is invalid for SSH RSA.");
        }
        String keyStr = matcher.group(1);

        ByteArrayInputStream is = new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64.decodeBase64(keyStr));

        byte[] prefix = new byte[INITIAL_PREFIX.length];

        try {
            if (INITIAL_PREFIX.length != is.read(prefix) || !ArrayUtils.isEquals(INITIAL_PREFIX, prefix)) {
                throw new InvalidKeyException("Initial [ssh-rsa] key prefix missed.");
            }

            BigInteger exponent = getValue(is);
            BigInteger modulus = getValue(is);

            return (RSAPublicKey) KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent));
        } catch (IOException | InvalidKeySpecException | NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new InvalidKeyException("Failed to read SSH RSA certificate from string", e);
        }
    }

    private static BigInteger getValue(InputStream is) throws IOException {
        byte[] lenBuff = new byte[VALUE_LENGTH];
        if (VALUE_LENGTH != is.read(lenBuff)) {
            throw new InvalidParameterException("Unable to read value length.");
        }

        int len = ByteBuffer.wrap(lenBuff).getInt();
        byte[] valueArray = new byte[len];
        if (len != is.read(valueArray)) {
            throw new InvalidParameterException("Unable to read value.");
        }

        return new BigInteger(valueArray);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is an easily understood answer; however, a more expressive name for VALUE_LENGTH would be an improvement.

Answer (score 3):

You have to convert your key to pkcs8 spec. Use below command

```
ssh-keygen -f private.key -e -m pkcs8 > test-pkcs8.pub
```

Then convert it to  x509

```
openssl rsa -pubin -in test-pkcs8.pub -outform pem > test-x509.pem
```

You can then use below code to read the public key as RSAPublicKey in Java

```
import java.io.IOException;

import java.net.URISyntaxException;

import java.nio.file.Files;

import java.nio.file.Paths;

import java.security.KeyFactory;

import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

import java.security.PrivateKey;

import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;

import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;

import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;

import java.security.spec.X509EncodedKeySpec;

import java.util.Base64;


/**

* This file is intended to be used on a IDE for testing purposes.

* ClassLoader.getSystemResource won't work in a JAR

*/

public class Main {


    public static void main(String[] args) throws InvalidKeySpecException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, IOException, URISyntaxException {


        String privateKeyContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("private_key_pkcs8.pem").toURI())));

        String publicKeyContent = new String(Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(ClassLoader.getSystemResource("public_key.pem").toURI())));


        privateKeyContent = privateKeyContent.replaceAll("\\n", "").replace("-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----", "").replace("-----END PRIVATE KEY-----", "");

        publicKeyContent = publicKeyContent.replaceAll("\\n", "").replace("-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----", "").replace("-----END PUBLIC KEY-----", "");;


        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");


        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec keySpecPKCS8 = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(privateKeyContent));

        PrivateKey privKey = kf.generatePrivate(keySpecPKCS8);


        X509EncodedKeySpec keySpecX509 = new X509EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(publicKeyContent));

        RSAPublicKey pubKey = (RSAPublicKey) kf.generatePublic(keySpecX509);


        System.out.println(privKey);

        System.out.println(pubKey);

    }

}
```

Got the answer from below two links

[Converting ssh-rsa to X509 Spec in Java](https://gist.github.com/diorahman/274e667b0bb99d854806)

[Loading X509 spec key in Java as RSAPublicKey object](https://gist.github.com/destan/b708d11bd4f403506d6d5bb5fe6a82c5)

Hope this will give you some intuition.

Comment: `ssh-keygen -e -m pkcs8` actually does NOT produce PKCS8 but instead X.509 SPKI, which is already correct for Java _publickey_ except the PEM wrapping, so your `openssl rsa` does no good at all. Your code then works for the publickey, as the Q wants, but NOT the privatekey. (Though it would if you actually did have a PKCS8-clear privatekey.) And the working part was already in my answer to #39105031 in 2016, as I commented above on the Q.

Answer (score 2):

I found a lot of answers how to get the public key - but none of them actually contained the part how to get the openssh public key *as a string* - it got a special format.

Cudos to @Jcs and @James K Polk

This depends on BouncyCastle. It could probably be done without.

```
package cuul.stuff;

import lombok.SneakyThrows;
import org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.asymmetric.rsa.BCRSAPrivateCrtKey;
import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.KeyFactory;
import java.security.PrivateKey;
import java.security.Security;
import java.security.interfaces.RSAPublicKey;
import java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException;
import java.security.spec.PKCS8EncodedKeySpec;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;
import java.util.Base64;

/**
 * Takes an private SSH key and cranks out the corresponding public one.
 *
 * Just what this command would have done: <pre>ssh-keygen -y -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa > ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub</pre>
 *
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706177/how-to-generate-ssh-compatible-id-rsa-pub-from-java
 * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7216969/getting-rsa-private-key-from-pem-base64-encoded-private-key-file/7221381#7221381
 *
 * Why - because I can.
 */
public class ExtractPublicFromPrivateSshKey {

    private static final String BEGIN_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY = "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n";
    private static final String END_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY = "-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----";

    static {
        Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
    }

    @SneakyThrows
    public static String extract(String privateKeyString) {
        if (!privateKeyString.startsWith(BEGIN_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY)) {
            throw new InvalidKeySpecException("Can only extract public key from a RSA private. "
                    + "This is not an RSA key (header should have been '" + BEGIN_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY + "'");
        }

        privateKeyString = privateKeyString.replace(BEGIN_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY, "");
        privateKeyString = privateKeyString.replace(END_RSA_PRIVATE_KEY, "");
        privateKeyString = privateKeyString.trim();

        byte[] privateKeyBytes = Base64.getMimeDecoder().decode(privateKeyString);

        BCRSAPrivateCrtKey rsaPrivateKey = (BCRSAPrivateCrtKey) getPrivate(privateKeyBytes);

        //create a KeySpec and let the Factory due the Rest. You could also create the KeyImpl by your own.
        RSAPublicKey publicKey = (RSAPublicKey) KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(
                new RSAPublicKeySpec(rsaPrivateKey.getModulus(), rsaPrivateKey.getPublicExponent()));

        byte[] bytes = encodePublicKey(publicKey);
        return "ssh-rsa " + new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(bytes), StandardCharsets.UTF_8) + " some@user";
    }

    private static PrivateKey getPrivate(byte[] privateKeyBytes)
            throws Exception {
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(privateKeyBytes);
        KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
        return kf.generatePrivate(spec);
    }

    /**
     * @link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706177/how-to-generate-ssh-compatible-id-rsa-pub-from-java
     *
     * The key format used by ssh is defined in the RFC #4253. The format for RSA public key is the following :

     * string    "ssh-rsa"
     * mpint     e  // key public exponent
     * mpint     n  // key modulus
     *
     * All data type encoding is defined in the section #5 of RFC #4251. string and mpint (multiple precision integer) types are encoded this way :
     *
     * 4-bytes word: data length (unsigned big-endian 32 bits integer)
     * n bytes     : binary representation of the data
     *
     * or instance, the encoding of the string "ssh-rsa" is:
     *
     * byte[] data = new byte[] {0, 0, 0, 7, 's', 's', 'h', '-', 'r', 's', 'a'};
     */
    private static byte[] encodePublicKey(RSAPublicKey key) throws IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        /* encode the "ssh-rsa" string */
        byte[] sshrsa = new byte[] {0, 0, 0, 7, 's', 's', 'h', '-', 'r', 's', 'a'};
        out.write(sshrsa);
        /* Encode the public exponent */
        BigInteger e = key.getPublicExponent();
        byte[] data = e.toByteArray();
        encodeUInt32(data.length, out);
        out.write(data);
        /* Encode the modulus */
        BigInteger m = key.getModulus();
        data = m.toByteArray();
        encodeUInt32(data.length, out);
        out.write(data);
        return out.toByteArray();
    }

    private static void encodeUInt32(int value, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] tmp = new byte[4];
        tmp[0] = (byte)((value >>> 24) & 0xff);
        tmp[1] = (byte)((value >>> 16) & 0xff);
        tmp[2] = (byte)((value >>> 8) & 0xff);
        tmp[3] = (byte)(value & 0xff);
        out.write(tmp);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Code for getting `PublicKey` object from `.pub` file generated through ssh-keygen.

`RSAPublicKeySpec` constructor looks like this

```
public RSAPublicKeySpec(BigInteger modulus, BigInteger publicExponent)
```

So we need to extract `modulus` and `publicExponent` from `.pub` file and pass it to the constructor to create `RSAPublicKeySpec`. Once we have the spec we can generate `PublicKey` using `KeyFactory`.

```
private PublicKey decodePublicKey() {
    try {
        // input stream of .pub file
        InputStream inputStream = new ClassPathResource("keys/test_public_key.key").getInputStream(); 
        String keyLine = StreamUtils.copyToString(inputStream, Charset.defaultCharset());
        String[] parts = keyLine.split(" ");
        for (String part : parts) {
            if (part.startsWith("AAAA")) {
                byte[] decodeBuffer = Base64Utils.decode(part.getBytes());
                ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.wrap(decodeBuffer);
                /* using 4 bytes from bb to generate integer which gives us length of key- 
                format type, in this case len=7 as "ssh-rsa" has 7 chars  
                */
                int len = bb.getInt(); 
                byte[] type = new byte[len];
                bb.get(type);
                if ("ssh-rsa".equals(new String(type))) {
                    // extracting exponent and modulus from remaining byte-buffer
                    BigInteger exponent = decodeBigInt(bb);
                    BigInteger modulus = decodeBigInt(bb);
                    RSAPublicKeySpec spec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, exponent);
                    return KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA").generatePublic(spec);
                } else {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Only supporta RSA");
                }
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

```
private BigInteger decodeBigInt(ByteBuffer bb) {
    // use first 4 bytes to generate an Integer that gives the length of bytes to create BigInteger
    int len = bb.getInt();
    byte[] bytes = new byte[len];
    bb.get(bytes);
    return new BigInteger(bytes);
}
```

References :

- https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration-samples/blob/master/basic/sftp/src/test/java/org/springframework/integration/samples/sftp/EmbeddedSftpServer.java
- https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4253.txt

Answer (score 1):

Late response but I had the same issue and came up with the following: You'll need Apache commons-io and guava libraries

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.math.BigInteger;
import java.security.spec.RSAPublicKeySpec;

import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

import com.google.common.base.Splitter;
import com.google.common.io.ByteSource;
import com.google.common.io.ByteStreams;
import com.google.common.base.Charsets;

import static com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkArgument;
import static com.google.common.collect.Iterables.get;
import static com.google.common.collect.Iterables.size;
import static com.google.common.io.BaseEncoding.base64;

public class SSHEncodedToRSAPublicConverter {

  private static final String SSH_MARKER = "ssh-rsa";

  private ByteSource supplier;

  public SSHEncodedToRSAPublicConverter(String fileName) {
    this(new File(fileName));
  }

  public SSHEncodedToRSAPublicConverter(File file) {
    try {
      byte[] data = IOUtils.toByteArray(new FileInputStream(file));
      this.supplier = ByteSource.wrap(data);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
  }

  public SSHEncodedToRSAPublicConverter(byte[] data) {
    this.supplier = ByteSource.wrap(data);
  }

  /**
   * Converts an SSH public key to a x.509 compliant format RSA public key spec
   * Source: https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds/blob/master/compute/src/main/java/org/jclouds/ssh/SshKeys.java
   * @return RSAPublicKeySpec
   */
  public RSAPublicKeySpec convertToRSAPublicKey() {
    try {
      InputStream stream = supplier.openStream();
      Iterable<String> parts = Splitter.on(' ').split(IOUtils.toString(stream, Charsets.UTF_8));
      checkArgument(size(parts) >= 2 && SSH_MARKER.equals(get(parts,0)), "bad format, should be: ssh-rsa AAAB3....");
      stream = new ByteArrayInputStream(base64().decode(get(parts, 1)));
      String marker = new String(readLengthFirst(stream));
      checkArgument(SSH_MARKER.equals(marker), "looking for marker %s but received %s", SSH_MAKER, marker);
      BigInteger publicExponent = new BigInteger(readLengthFirst(stream));
      BigInteger modulus = new BigInteger(readLengthFirst(stream));
      RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, publicExponent);
      return keySpec;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
  }

  private static byte[] readLengthFirst(InputStream in) throws IOException {
    int[] bytes = new int[]{ in.read(), in.read(), in.read(), in.read() };
    int length = 0;
    int shift = 24;
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
      length += bytes[i] << shift;
      shift -= 8;
    }
    byte[] val = new byte[length];
    ByteStreams.readFully(in, val);
    return val;
  }
}
```

Then to use it you can do something like:

```
File keyFile = new File("id_rsa.pub");
Keyspec spec = new SSHEncodedToRSAPublicConverter(keyFile).convertToRSAPublicKey();
KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
Key key = kf.generatePublic(spec);
```

I got the conversion (special thanks) portion from the following link:

https://github.com/jclouds/jclouds/blob/master/compute/src/main/java/org/jclouds/ssh/SshKeys.java